# Operation which needs much computing power to be created, but just a little to be solved?

Tags: encryption

Does somebody know a cryptographic/mathematic operation, that needs much computing power to be "encrypted"/"created" but doesn't need much power to be "decrypted"/"solved"?

Comment: That's pretty much the basis of [much of cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function).

Comment: @StephenTouset : $\:$ How? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @StephenTouset I think what Ricky Demer means is that much of cryptography is based around problems for which  $f(x) = y$ is simple but determining $x$ from $y$ is difficult. Those are (missing a lot of rigor) the type of trapdoor functions you are referring to, and that's different than what the question is seeking. The closest thing I can think of to what stereo_ is looking for would be proof-of-work systems, but I'm not quite sure they fit the bill. Can you (stereo_) expand possibly on what you are looking for or why you are looking for it?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I had completely inverted his question in my head — he wants the inverse of a trapdoor function. In a sense, he's looking for problems in NP: hard to compute, easy to verify.

Comment: @SamuelJudson I'd like to have such a problem for a crypto CTF. It should be a problem which is hard to compute (and needs a lot of resources to create) but is easy (with very limited resources) to solve for the participants of the CTF.

Comment: @stereo_ Why is that "hard to compute" part necessary? It seems like all that would do would be to make it hard to generate games. Can you maybe describe how you want the game to work?

Comment: I'd comment but, sigh I lack the creds. This is one specific example of such a problem, similar to what's already been mentioned:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash)

Comment: The "just a little to be solved" part is easy: declare that 0 is always a solution. $\;$

Comment: I'd like to answer, but I've got a sudoku to solve.

Comment: You could also check the different proofs of work (or similar) used in the cryptocurrencies world. It usually looks like to find a preimage for a hash function.

Comment: @stereo_: What's _"a crypto [CTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTF)"_ in your [comment](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19779/operation-which-needs-much-computing-power-to-be-created-but-just-a-little-to-b#comment45926_19779) about the use case? $\;$ Does a [Proof-of-Work system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) combined to adding the plaintext in clear to the problem fits your needs? If not, why? Note: answer that my clarifying your question (hopefully, you can use the edit button).

Answer (score 3):

Lots of problems are hard to solve but easy to check. For example:

1. finding hash pre-images of particular values such as 0
2. calculating discrete logs of small numbers modulo a prime
3. finding the factors of a large composite of a special form like $2^p-1$

I don't think there's an essential difference between solving and checking they're just arbitrary descriptions of the operations.

I imagine an unstated requirement of your question is that it should not be possible to pretend to have solved hard problems by generating random solutions and then saying that you arrived at the solution by solving the hard reverse problem. 
This is a bit like shooting arrows randomly into a wood and then painting targets round the arrows wherever they have stuck in the trees.

Answer (score -1):

Play with SBOX in AES. The encryption using the standard one is faster than the decryption. If you search you can find one with your specifications.